# Process yields a Process in Python using Simpy

Tags: python, simpy

I'm having a problem with my code.
I am using the Simpy for Python and I'm trying to make a P2P simulator utilizing Simpy.

Bellow is the code of my generator of peers, I don't know why but I never enter in the function `generate()`. The console don't shows the `print('I am here')`.

Anyone knows what I'm doing wrong on my code? Sorry if I'm doing something very wrong.

```
import simpy
import random

# PARAMETERS
RANDOM_SEED = 93817
N_NODES = 10  # 2000
RUN_TIME = 10  # 86400  # 24 hours
TIME_TO_GENERATE = 3  # at each 3 seconds

# FUNCTIONS


def peer(env, N_PEER):
    print('Peer %d join at %d' % (N_PEER, env.now))


def chanceToGenerate():
    value = random.random()*100
    if value < 50:
        return False
    else:
        return True


def generate(env, N_PEER):
    print('I am here')
    chance = chanceToGenerate()
    if chance:
        yield env.process(peer(env, N_PEER))
        return True
    else:
        return False


def peerGenerator(env):
    N_PEER = 0
    while True:
        if N_PEER < N_NODES:
            generated = generate(env, N_PEER)
            if generated:
                N_PEER += 1
        print('time: %d' % env.now)
        yield env.timeout(TIME_TO_GENERATE)


# RUNNING
random.seed(RANDOM_SEED)
env = simpy.Environment()

env.process(peerGenerator(env))

env.run(until=RUN_TIME)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem, what was my solution ?
Answer: I removed the function `generate()` and moved the `yield env.process(peer(env, N_PEER))` to the function`generator()`.

Why I did that?
I have been reading the documentation of [Simpy](https://simpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topical_guides/process_interaction.html) and I found out that I can't make a non-process yields another process. So only the peerGenerator() function can yields another process.

Code:

```
import simpy
import random

# PARAMETERS
RANDOM_SEED = 93817
N_NODES = 10  # 2000
RUN_TIME = 10  # 86400  # 24 hours
TIME_TO_GENERATE = 3  # at each 3 seconds

# FUNCTIONS


class peerGenerator:
    def __init__(self, env):
        self.env = env
        self.generator_proc = env.process(self.generator(env))

    def peer(self, env, N_PEER):
        print('Peer %d join at %d' % (N_PEER, env.now))
        yield env.timeout(0)

    def chanceToGenerate(self):
        value = random.randint(0,100)
        if value < 50:
            print('Tried to create a peer')
            return False
        else:
            return True


    def generator(self, env):
        N_PEER = 0
        while True:
            if N_PEER < N_NODES:
                chance = self.chanceToGenerate()
                if chance:
                    yield env.process(self.peer(env, N_PEER))
                    N_PEER += 1
            print('time: %d' % env.now)
            yield env.timeout(TIME_TO_GENERATE)


# RUNNING
env = simpy.Environment()

bootstrap = peerGenerator(env)

env.run(until=RUN_TIME)
```